# How can I generate a PHP array from icons CSS class names using jQuery?

Tags: php, jquery, css

I am trying to develop a PHP array generator from CSS class names.

Here the CSS code -

```
.sli-user:before {
  content: "\e005";
}
.sli-people:before {
  content: "\e001";
}
.sli-user-female:before {
  content: "\e000";
}
```

This is my jQuery code -

```
$("#generate").on("click",function(){
        $output = '';
        $icon_class    = $('#input_str').val();

        $icon_class = $icon_class.replace(/\./g, ' ');
        $icon_class = $icon_class.replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm,"");
        $icon_class = $icon_class.replace(/\s/g, '');


        $arr = $icon_class.split(':before');
        console.log($arr);
        for(i=0; i < $arr.length; i++){
            if ( $arr[i].length > 0 ) { 
                $output += "'"+$arr[i]+"' => '"+$arr[i]+"',\n";

            }
        }

        $('#output_str').val($output);
    });
```

And this is how I want it -

```
'sli-user' => 'sli-user',
'sli-people' => 'sli-people',
'sli-user-female' => 'sli-user-female',
```

Comment: If you make a jsfiddle I can help out

Comment: The equivalent form of an associative array in php is a javascript object.  You just have to make your object with the key value pairs.